# Funnel Chart in R

Tags: r, plotly, background-color

We created a funnel chart using R script but we are not able to change the background color from white to color `#00355c`.

Code used :

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
  type = "funnel",
   y = c("Invoiced", "Cancelled", "Collected", "Write Off", "Out Standing"),
  x = c(ZF_ZFO2CV001_OTC_002$`Net Invoiced (ABS)`,
ZF_ZFO2CV001_OTC_002$`Cancelled (Net Invoiced)`,
ZF_ZFO2CV001_OTC_002$`collected (ABS)`,
ZF_ZFO2CV001_OTC_002$`Write Off (ABS)`,
ZF_ZFO2CV001_OTC_002$`Outstanding Amount`)) 

fig <- fig %>%
   layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Invoiced", "Cancelled", "Collected", "Write Off", "Out Standing")))

fig
```

The expectation is to have a background color changed from white to `#00355c`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `plot_bgcolor`, `paper_bgcolor`, or both in `layout()`.

I've used gray and the color you identified to show which argument does what. Check it out:

```
library(plotly)

(fig <- plot_ly(type = "funnel", 
               y = c("Invoiced", "Cancelled", "Collected", "Write Off", "Outstanding"),
               x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 8)) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Invoiced", "Cancelled", "Collected", 
                                        "Write Off", "Outstanding")),
         plot_bgcolor = "#00355c", paper_bgcolor = "gray"))
```

[image]